# How do I use textcontentType .oneTimeCode to autofill OTP to my text field with SMS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, autofill

Yes, I have given text field delegate and text content type `.oneTimeCode` and the settings for autofillpassword is enabled.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var tf: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tf.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
    tf.keyboardType = .numberPad
    tf.becomeFirstResponder()
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print("textFieldDidBeginEditing --- ",textField.text)
}

@objc func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField){
    print("text =---- ,textFiel",textField.text)
    
}
```

And my text message has the word "code" current SMS format is "Your xxxx OTP Code is :7777"

I tried creating a new project with a page having a text field. I tried setting the content type via storyboard as well, but nothing works out.

Aim:

I'm trying to autofill the code from SMS to my text field. No method is getting triggered with textfielddelegate nor it is autofilling the text field with contenttype `.oneTimeCode`.

Comment: Cast your controller to UITextFieldDelegate, and set the delegate property on your UITextField to the controller (tf.delegate = self) to see if you get any events there

Comment: @schnabler I have done that but still no improvements, it should be automatically getting the code to textfield that doesn't work

Comment: @schnabler actually I am seeing the otp code above keyboard in prediction ,but there is some weird behaviour in my whole app the prediction doesn't work any where like a name text field also, i see the prediction but if I click it it doesn't work, it is like the userInteraction is disabled